# How to calculate when a specific value of a logistic curve is reached?

Tags: calculus, exact-sequence, subgroup-growth

I have a growth curve defined by a logistic term as:
$$N_t = rN_0(1-\frac{N_0}{\kappa})$$
I would like to find when a specific value of N is reached. Let's say I have these parameters:
$$\kappa = 10^{13}$$
$$r = 2$$
$$N_0 = 10^{4}$$
when would $10^6$ copies be reached? How many iteractions are exactly needed?

If I plug the values in I get:
$$10^6 \not = 2 \cdot 10^4 \cdot (1-\frac{10^4}{10^{13}}) \not \sim 20,000 $$
What is the right way to solve it? If I run it with a for loop, I get:

```
t = 1, N = 20,000 
t = 2, N = 40,000 
t = 3, N = 80,000 
t = 4, N = 160,000 
t = 5, N = 320,000 
t = 6, N = 640,000 
t = 7, N = 1,280,000
```

Which means N = 1,000,000 is reached before interaction 7. But at what exact $t$?

Thank you

Comment: Where is $t$ on the RHS of your equation?

Comment: Should it be $N_{t-1}$ instead of $N_0$?

Comment: As $N_t=10^6$ at some $6<t<7$, the recurrence will trace it back to some initial $N_t$ at $0<t<1$. Since these are not specified, there is no unique solution. Perhaps you can interpolate.

Comment: Some papers report t and 0, others t and t+1 or t-1 and t, but I think the subscripts say the same thing. But the problem is indeed that there is no t in these equations, thus I can't solve for it. How would I do interpolation?